# jQuery hover on HTML tree

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a standard HTML ul tree:

```
<ul id="catTree">
    <li>Header 1 <span>(blah)</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Branch 1 <span>(blah)</span></li>
            <li>Branch2 <span>(blah)</span></li>
```

...
And some jQuery:

```
    $('#catTree li').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children('span').css('display','inline');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children('span').css('display','none');
        }
    );
```

The default CSS hides the spans, and the jQuery shows them.  It works fine, except that as well as the actual branch being hovered, every parent also shows the spans. 
so on a hover, it looks like:

```
Header 1 (blah)
    Branch1 (blah)
```

rather than

```
Header1
    Branch1 (blah)
```

I get why (because both LIs are hovered), but how can I tell jQuery to not fire the hovers on the parents?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
//Note the selector.
//Only the children li's will be selected
$('#catTree ul > li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children('span').css('display','inline');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children('span').css('display','none');
  }
);
```

Comment: This still fires the hover on the parent as well

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you stop the propagation :

```
$('#catTree li').hover(
        function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children('span').css('display','inline');
        },
        function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children('span').css('display','none');
        }
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/B5ZwE/

Although if you hover first on the header then hover on its' children it's not considered as hovering out.

Comment: @Mark's answer about inner span is correct although dirty. Can't figure out how to correctly hover it only using li. Using span, i would rather use CSS :hover selector which is way faster.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent ages thinking about it, 30sec later I worked it out after posting...

Don't hover on the LIs (because the parent LI covers the children), hover on an extra span instead:

```
<ul id="catTree">
<li><span>Header 1 <span>(blah)</span> </span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Branch 1 <span>(blah)</span> </span></li>
        <li><span>Branch2 <span>(blah)</span></span></li>
```

and

```
       $(function() {
    $('#catTree li>span').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children('span').css('display','inline');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children('span').css('display','none');
        }
    );

});
```